# How to define a function that the argv is not at the end of the command in fish-shell

Tags: shell, fish

If I want to make a `find` short for

`find dir_name -type d`

to `fd`

then I can just use `fd dir_name` to do the command.

How can define a `function` or make an `alias` to do the trick

It would be better if I can even do this: `fd dir-name other_operations` which equals to

`find dir_name -type d other_operations` in Terminal.

The fish-shell built-in documentation has no info about this.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if `fish` follows POSIX shells modestly well, then a function such as one of these might do the trick.

```
fd() {
    find "$@" -type d
}
```

Or:

```
fd() {
    dir="$1"
    shift
    find "$dir" -type d "$@"
}
```

The first assumes that all the arguments are directories or operands that can precede `-type d`.  The second assumes that there is a single directory and then other arguments.

Apart from details of notation, it is likely that you can implement something similar in `fish`.

---

Of course, if you go to http://fishshell.com/ and in particular the documentation for how to create a [function](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#function), you find that there is limited similarity in syntax.

```
function fd
    find $argv -type d
end

function fd
    find $argv[1] -type d $argv[2..-1]
end
```

---

The last function only works if there are at least 2 arguments passed to the function.  'Tis curious; elsewhere non-existent variables expand to nothing, but not in array expansions like this.  There is a (built-in) command `count` which can be used to determine how many elements are in an array: `count $argv` will return the number of elements in the array.

Hence a revised version of the code would be:

```
function fd
    if test (count $argv) -gt 1
        find $argv[1] -type d $argv[2..-1]
    else
        find $argv[1] -type d
    end
end
```

Comment: Oh god, it's `$argv`, I mistook it for `@argv`, actually if I `functions fd` it will show the detail, I tried `find @argv -type d`, it just should be `find $argv -type d`. My bad. Thank you for your last part.

Answer (score 3):

You would define a function like so:

```
function fd
    find $argv -type d
end
```

The arguments to the function are passed in the `$argv` list. You are free to slice and dice them before passing them on to find.

Answer (score 0):

#### Thanks for @Jonathan Leffler, this couldn't be without his help:

---

As for his answer, the last part of `$argv[2..-1]`(or `$argv[2...-1]`) is not right, it seems that `fish-shell` doesn't support this kind of syntax, it says:

```
Could not expand string “$argv[2..-1]
```

**Actually** after a few tests, it turns out that part is unnecessary, `fish-shell` will automatically parses the rest of `$argv` if `$argv` is a list.

---

### The right template is(already tested, So simple):

```
function fd --description 'List all the (sub)directory names in a direction'
    find $argv[1] -type d
end
```

Comment: I'm disappointed that you no longer think my answer provided you with any help.  I don't mind it being unaccepted; my original answer wasn't quite perfect.  I had to learn a new shell to provide you with the correct syntax, so I got something out of it (though I'm not sure I'm going to become a convert to `fish`).  But I do feel you probably got some value out of it.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Easy, the fact is, I was trying to append my above answer into yours(edit yours), but my browser(or network) is very slow to load the StackOverflow from time to time. After I appended it into your answer I couldn't submit, I tried several times(close tab, restart browser), it just failed. So I have to answer it myself. A comment already have been made that you helped, the right solution of mime here couldn't be without yours. As for the `upvote`, I can upvote it if you like. But your answer won't be accepted since it was not the straight answer. Hope you can understand. :-)

Comment: An upvote indicates 'this answer is useful' (for any definition of useful).  The accepted answer is accepted because 'it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution' (quoting from the text that appears when you hover over an accept icon).  Your decision about what to do, and thank you for the upvote if it is yours.  There's nothing that says you can only upvote one answer as helpful; there's nothing that says you have to accept an answer, but doing so does bring a form of closure to the question.